# Как работать с драйвером?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Приветствую!
Есть usb устройство система распознала его и установила драйвер. Есть дамп работы устройства со специальной программой(hex коды обмена данными). Вопрос можно ли написать программу на C++ для взаимодействия с этим устройством? Что можно почитать по этой задаче?

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Написать теоретически можно. Но нужно смотреть как программа общается с драйвером, а  не дамп обмена по порту.

Comment: а как это можно посмотреть? (есть утилита?)

Comment: В общем случае программы пользовательского режима взаимодействуют с драйверами путем отрытия дескриптора драйвера функцией `CreateFile("\\\\.\\DEVICE\\devicename", ...)` и обмена пакетами данных с помощью `DeviceIoControl(hDevice, ...)`.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, WinAPI путь - взаимодействовать с объектом, который этот драйвер обслуживает. Думаю, что хорошим примером будет устройство `"\\\\.\\COM1" и его специфический API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой статье [AntiHASP: эмулируем ключ аппаратной защиты HASP](http://www.xakep.ru/post/57901/?print=true)

Предложен вариант создания эмулятора в виде драйвера-перехватчика IRP пакетов. Исходники к тексту - поищи в интернете, возможно кто-то выкладывал. Статья и примеры полностью соответствуют описанной тобой задаче.

Answer (score -1):

Windows предлагает строго по АПИ взаимодействовать с устройствами.
Общее алгоритм сводиться к этому: сначала нужно отловить скажем так хэндлер к устройству, потом можно как с файлом работать, открыть, считывать, записывать что либо.
Но это простейший алгоритм для com портов. А с юзб устройствами дело намного сложнее.
Их проста так не откроешь(сам попробовал считывать с юзб принтера, не получился)
Думаю вам нужно посмотреть на сторону Windows Driver KIt.

Comment: Ситуация осложняется тем что родное по использует java для работы с устройством(